# How can I use Bootstrap 4 flexbox to force a sidebar column menu to simply switch to top column menu when in mobile viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

As it stands now, the menu first switches to horizontal top (above rest of content), then wraps so that one or two items are on the first row and the rest on the second row, and finally when the screen is small enough, it turns into a column. I want it to ALWAYS be a column, and when the screen gets too small for the sidebar, to switch over to the top.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row h-100">
    <!-- left sidebar -->
    <div class="col-lg-2 fixed pl-0 py-3 ">

        <ul class="nav flex-md-column ">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">dddddddddddddddddddddddd</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- center content -->
    <div class="sc-content col fluid bg-faded ">


        <h4 class="mt-3">Now that Bootstrap 4 has a flexbox grid it's much easier to create a fixed-fluid layout like this one.</h4>
        <p>Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
            modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
        <p>What will you do with this new awesomeness in Bootstrap 4?</p>

    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 fixed py-3">
        <!---leave nothing here, just to make text centered. Alternatively, add a right sidebar later.-->
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: - to turn it into a column any time , use the built-in `flex-column` class. // - ?? *to switch over to the top* , can you clarify, i do not understand this part .(my average english probably ;) )

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I shouldn't have been using flex-md-column. I like it. If you post it as an answer I will pick it as best. BONUS: figure out how to center the menu items when on top.

Comment: EDIT: I mean, when the menu jumps on top of the content, when the screen is small - just make it center-aligned. Now it's on the top left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in class `flex-column` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction

> Set the direction of `flex` items in a flex container with direction utilities. In most cases you can omit the horizontal class here as the browser default is `row`. However, you may encounter situations where you needed to explicitly set this value (like responsive layouts).
>
> Use `.flex-row` to set a horizontal direction (the browser default), or `.flex-row-reverse` to start the horizontal direction from the opposite side.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row h-100">
    <!-- left sidebar -->
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 fixed pl-0 py-3 ">

        <ul class="nav flex-column ">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">dddddddddddddddddddddddd</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- center content -->
    <div class="sc-content col fluid bg-faded ">


        <h4 class="mt-3">Now that Bootstrap 4 has a flexbox grid it's much easier to create a fixed-fluid layout like this one.</h4>
        <p>Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia cor magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
            modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
        <p>What will you do with this new awesomeness in Bootstrap 4?</p>

    </div>
   <div class="col-lg-2 fixed py-3">
        <!---leave nothing here, just to make text centered. Alternatively, add a right sidebar later.-->
    </div>
```

you might also use `col-sm-x` classes to span the navigation, if i understood the other part of the queston.